# text conversion logic to handle currency related text in python

Tags: python

```
def money_con(string_value):
    str_list = string_value.split(" ")
    new_list = []
    for index,char in enumerate(str_list):
        if char == "lakhs":
            res = int(str_list[index-1]) * 100000
            new_list.append(str(res))
        else:
            new_list.append(str_list[index])
    return new_list


string_value = "25 lakhs only"
res = money_con(string_value)
print(res)
```

Expected output: ['2500000', 'only']

Actual output: ['25', '2500000', 'only']

I am working on inverse text normalization to handle currency-related text data like lakhs and convert it to its corresponding value along with the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about what you are saying with your if-else statement this should be clear. You are saying that `if char == "lakhs"` you do a calculation on the previous index. In **all** other cases, i.e. `else` you append straight to the list.

To avoid this you could use `elif` instead and give some statement to when to run the code inside elif.

Here is a suggestion (and a lot of prints so that you can see what is going on)

```
def money_con(string_value):
    str_list = string_value.split(" ")
    new_list = []
    for index,char in enumerate(str_list):
        print("i:", index, "ch", char)
        if char == "lakhs":
            print("inside if")
            res = int(str_list[index-1]) * 100000
            new_list.append(str(res))
        elif char == "only":
            print("inside else\ni:", index, "ch", char)
            new_list.append(str_list[index])
    return new_list


string_value = "25 lakhs only"
res = money_con(string_value)
print(res)
```

Here is the output:

```
i: 0 ch 25
i: 1 ch lakhs
inside if
i: 2 ch only
inside else
i: 2 ch only
['2500000', 'only']
```